# How to create a cronjob backup for mysql slave?

Tags: mysql, cron, centos

There are few other threads about this question using mysqldump but however i tend to not use mysqldump but instead backup the whole files in /mysql.

I would like to create a cronjob in mysql slave which only involves `start slave` and `stop slave`.

I only know how to use crontab with starting and stopping mysql (as below). Instead i have no idea how to insert start and stop slave in crontab. Any help?

`0 19 * * * service mysql stop;rsync -avzr -e 'ssh -p 22' /home/mysql /home/DAILY-BACKUP-SQL;service mysql start`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: You can start and stop replication from the shell with `mysqladmin`:

```
mysqladmin --help
...
  start-slave       Start slave
  stop-slave        Stop slave
...
```

This is basically just running `STOP SLAVE` and `START SLAVE` statements. You could also run those statements yourself:

```
mysql -e "STOP SLAVE"
mysql -e "START SLAVE"
```

However, I would strongly recommend against making a backup by using `rsync` on a running MySQL Server. It does not help to stop replication, because there are other asynchronous threads running in a MySQL Server. You can't be sure when you do your `rsync` that all the data changes have been merged into the proper place. Therefore they still could be doing their background work at the same time your `rsync` is trying to copy the tablespace files.

By using a physical file copy method without stopping the mysqld process, you will end up copying an inconsistent backup that cannot be restored.

If you want to make a physical backup instead of using `mysqldump`, then try Percona XtraBackup. This is a free product. It works by copying tablespaces and redo logs in sync, so you get a consistent backup. It's not as simple to use as `rsync` or even `mysqldump`, but fortunately it will not corrupt your backup. At my job, we use this product to back up over 3,000 MySQL instances in production every night.

See https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup

Comment: Thank you very much. I got much clearer picture now how to plan the backup. The reason i''m doing physical backup is due to the huge database files. I could not afford to spend more time on mysqldump whenever emergency restoration comes. Percona XtraBackup is the best alternative i heard so far.

Comment: Right, restoration of a physical backup made with XtraBackup is very quick. It has the advantage you're looking for, but it solves the problem of inconsistent backups when you use it on a running instance of mysqld.